# La subconsulta ha devuelto mas de una fila

Tags: mysql

Hola tengo este problema con una consulta

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER pagos AFTER INSERT ON Pagos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @puesto = (SELECT e.puesto FROM Empleado AS e, Pagos AS p WHERE 
e.idEmpleado=p.Empleado_idEmpleado);
IF @puesto='Administrador' THEN
CALL Administrador(new.Empleado_idEmpleado);
END IF;
IF @puesto='Gerente administrativo' THEN
CALL Gerente_administrativo(new.Empleado_idEmpleado);
END IF;
IF @puesto='Coordinador' THEN
CALL Coordinador(new.Empleado_idEmpleado);
END IF;
IF @puesto='Jefaturas' THEN
CALL Jefaturas(new.Empleado_idEmpleado);
END IF;
IF @puesto='Secretarias' THEN
CALL Secretarias(new.Empleado_idEmpleado);
END IF;
IF @puesto='Intendente' THEN
CALL Intendente(new.Empleado_idEmpleado);
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

tengo este trigger con el que quiero que me evalue el puesto de los empleados que estan recibiendo un pago el problema es que cuando inserto los id de los empleados en la tabla pagos me manda un error al hacer la consulta dentro del trigger:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando ejecutas

```
SELECT e.puesto FROM Empleado AS e, Pagos AS p WHERE 
e.idEmpleado=p.Empleado_idEmpleado
```

¿cuántos registros obtienes? Mira que no lo estás limitando en el WHERE con ninguna variable dentro del trigger, así que estás obteniendo siempre la lista completa de puestos de la tabla `Empleado` para todos los puestos con `Pagos`. Y, como esperas un valor único que quieres asignar a la variable, sale el error que te muestra.

Trata de limitar la consulta usando algo como `WHERE... AND new.Empleado_idEmpleado = p.Empleado_idEmpleado` para que tenga relación con el registro que acabas de crear en la tabla y tenga sentido su ejecución dentro del trigger.